# Sphinx Configuration to handle German Umlauts

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm using this index configuration:

```
index humans
{
    source                = src_humans
    path                  = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/humans
    charset_table         = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+C4->U+E4, U+D6->U+F6, U+DC->U+FC, U+DF, U+E4, U+F6, U+FC
    html_strip            = 1
    html_index_attrs      = img=src,alt; a=href,title
    morphology            = libstemmer_de
    min_infix_len         = 3
    stopwords             = /tmp/stopwords_de.txt
}
```

My indexer runs through:

```
Sphinx 2.3.1-id64-beta (r4926)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'humans'...
WARNING: index 'humans': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 2 docs, 989 bytes
total 0.043 sec, 22888 bytes/sec, 46.28 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 2.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 1.9 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=8908).
```

When I search with `$sc->Query('*gef*')` I get a found document with "Gefährlich" in its description, but not when I search with `$sc->Query('*gefä*')`.

What do I do wrong?
My whole MySQL-DB and every single file belonging to the project is UTF-8 encoded.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this behavior with
`sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

When I used Sphinx, I had in my `searchd` config something like

`collation_server     = utf8_general_ci`

And in my `index` config:

`charset_type        = utf-8`

I hope, it can help you

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work .. Sphinx shows up a warning, too: `WARNING: key 'charset_type' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.`

Comment: Damned, I'm reading the current documentation in *2.6. Sphinx deprecations and changes in default configuration*: _charset_type=sbcs is now deprecated, we're slowly switching to UTF-only_ .
I notice you use a beta version; be careful!
Can you check `$sc->Query('*gefär*')` if the issue concern the union with special char and joker. I don't beleive, but why not.

Comment: I just downgraded Sphinx to the stable release. Unfortunately its the same behavior.
What do you mean with your last sentence?

(Answer too long, full version: http://pastie.org/pastes/10084695/text?key=hx6mkhglfdbtfrq8ser5zq)

Comment: Can you test with `morphology = none`? 
Have you tried to query in SphinxQL for debugging?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with morphology = none, but I didn't try SphinxQL - I will try that later.